～たまま with transitive and intransitive verbs
I am wondering what is the difference between

汚したまま
なぜ便器を汚したままで出るんですか

and

汚れたまま
コンピューターを汚れたままにした

When should you use Transitive and when Intransitive version of the verb when using まま?
What are the differences?

You'll notice that in the second case there's a “〜にした” behind it and “する” is transitive. The object of said “する” in this case is “コンピューターを” so that's why the intransitive version is used, as in to make the computer “汚れたまま”. Alternatively “コンプーターを汚したままにした” would work just as well but as well but then it basically means “make [the situation] so that the computer was left in the state where it was made dirty.” rather than “make the computer to remain in a state where it got dirty” for an awkward, literal translation of either that conveys the underlying grammar. Either comes down to the same “Left the computer dirty.” for an idiomatic translation.
In the first case there is no second “〜にする” verb so the intransitive version wouldn't be grammatical as some verb has to take “便器を” as the object and it simply means “Why would you come out with the toilet left dirty.” Note that “なぜ便器が汚れたままで出てるんですか？” is grammatical here again.
As for the difference in meaning, the transitive version implies someone made it dirty and the intransitive version means it might as well got dirty on it's own. For instance in “エンジンオイルが汚れたままで走ったらどんな症状がでます”, using “エンジンオイルを汚したままで” here implies someone made the engine oil dirty, which usually doesn't make much sense.

That's exactly what I thought. Thanks for clearing everything up!
